# Object object being displayed when trying to render blockContent on React

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I am working on a website and trying to render a blockContent from Sanity.io, in my React application, but it's displayed as only [object Object] on the website. I tried different queries on Sanity Vision, and got the data but nothing seems to work, so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my blockContent schema code:

```
export default {
  title: 'Block Content',
  name: 'blockContent',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    {
      title: 'Block',
      type: 'block',
      // Styles let you set what your user can mark up blocks with. These
      // correspond with HTML tags, but you can set any title or value
      // you want and decide how you want to deal with it where you want to
      // use your content.
      styles: [
        {title: 'Normal', value: 'normal'},
        {title: 'H1', value: 'h1'},
        {title: 'H2', value: 'h2'},
        {title: 'H3', value: 'h3'},
        {title: 'H4', value: 'h4'},
        {title: 'Quote', value: 'blockquote'},
      ],
      lists: [{title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet'}],
      // Marks let you mark up inline text in the block editor.
      marks: {
        // Decorators usually describe a single property – e.g. a typographic
        // preference or highlighting by editors.
        decorators: [
          {title: 'Strong', value: 'strong'},
          {title: 'Emphasis', value: 'em'},
        ],
        // Annotations can be any object structure – e.g. a link or a footnote.
        annotations: [
          {
            title: 'URL',
            name: 'link',
            type: 'object',
            fields: [
              {
                title: 'URL',
                name: 'href',
                type: 'url',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    // You can add additional types here. Note that you can't use
    // primitive types such as 'string' and 'number' in the same array
    // as a block type.
    {
      type: 'image',
      options: {hotspot: true},
    },
  ],
}
```

Here is the schema where I imported the blockContent:

```
export default {
  name: "aboutme",
  title: "About Me",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "description",
      title: "Description",
      type: "blockContent",
    },
    {
      name: "profileImg",
      title: "Profile Picture",
      type: "image",
      options: {
        hotspot: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "resume",
      title: "Resume",
      type: "file",
      options: {
        accept: "application/pdf",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Here is my jsx code where I am trying to display my contnent:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import { images } from "../../constants";
import { client, urlFor } from "../../client";
import { AppWrap, MotionWrap } from "../../wrapper";
import "./About.scss";
import BlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);
  const [aboutMe, setAboutMe] = useState({});
  const [aboutMeData, setAboutMeData] = useState(null);
  const { slug } = useParams();


  useEffect(() => {
    const aboutsQuery = '*[_type == "abouts"]';
    const aboutMeQuery = `*[_type == "aboutme"][0]{
      profileImg,
      description[0]{children[0]{"short_description" : text}},
     "resumeUrl": resume.asset -> url
    }`;
    client.fetch(aboutsQuery).then((data) => {
      setAbouts(data);
    });
    client.fetch(aboutMeQuery).then((data) => {
      setAboutMe(data);
      console.log(data)
    });
    client.fetch(
      `*[slug.current == "${slug}"]{
        description[0]{children[0]{"short_description" : text}}
      }`
  )
      .then((data) => setAboutMeData(data[0]));

  }, []);

  const viewResumeHandler = () => {
    window.open(aboutMe.resumeUrl, "_blank");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app__about-context app__flex">
        <div className="app__about-img app__flex">
          <div className="app__flex">
            <img
              src={
                aboutMe.profileImg
                  ? urlFor(aboutMe.profileImg)
                  : images.aboutmine
              }
              alt="Profile"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="app__about-data app__flex">
          <h2 className="head-text">About Me</h2>
          <p
            className="p-text"
            id="p-text-id"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: aboutMe.description }}
          ></p>

           <BlockContent
            blocks={aboutMeData}
            projectId="id" dataset="production"
          />

          <div>
            <button className="portfolio-button" onClick={viewResumeHandler}>
              Resume
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="app__profiles">
        {abouts.map((about, index) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.2, type: "tween" }}
            className="app__profile-item"
            key={about.title + index}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
            <h2 className="bold-text" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
              {about.title}
            </h2>
            <h2 className="p-text" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
              {about.description}
            </h2>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(About, "app__about"),
  "about",
  "app__whitebg"
);
```

The page displays but it only show [object Object] where I want to get the data displayed.

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: somewhere the object is converted to string and so is the `[object Object]`

Comment: `blocks` prop in `BlockContent` receives an array of portable text blocks. Are you totally sure `aboutMeData` is an array? Can you include a `console.log` of this state once it's populated?

Comment: Btw, the [block-content-to-react](https://github.com/sanity-io/block-content-to-react) package you are using is deprecated. they recommend the [react-portabletext](https://github.com/portabletext/react-portabletext) package instead of this package you are using. And this is the [migration guide](https://github.com/portabletext/react-portabletext/blob/main/MIGRATING.md). Maybe a conclusion can be drawn here.

Comment: Somewhere you are doing this
```js
const a={a:1}
`hello ${a}`
```
This will result as 
**Hello [object Object]**
I assume something wrong here.

```js
 <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
```
If you already have `about.imgUrl` why to pass it to a function `urlFor()`?